# There are 8 female and 6 male candidates for a committee. The committee will have 3 females and 2 males. How many committees will be formed?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 8 female and 6 male candidates for a committee. The committee will have 3 females and 2 males. How many committees will be formed?

In my probability class we got a solution that was

8 x 7 x 6 x 6 x 5= 20160

However, in our homework we had a problem in the homework that was the same (in my opinion, i could be wrong) :

A committee of 7, consisting of 2 Republicans, 2 Democrats, and 3 Independents, is to be chosen from a group of 5 Republicans, 6 Democrats, and 4 Independents. How many committees are possible?

The answer in the textbook says the solution is 5C2 x 6C2  x 4C3 = 600

If I were to solve the problem in class the way it was done in the notebook, I get a completely different answer.

My professor has been wrong a few times about how to do a problem so I just want to be sure if I am doing something wrong or if it he is doing something wrong as we have an exam coming up. Please help if you can!

Comment: The answer to the first problem calculates the number of ways one can order 3 female candidates followed by 2 male candidates. It does not seem to be counting the number of committees. The answer to the second problem seems correct.

Comment: The textbook answer is correct.  You should apply the same method to the problem you did in class.  That answer was incorrect.

Comment: Just to stress:  the number of ways to choose $5$ people from a group of $14$, with no restriction at all on gender, is $\binom {14}5=2002$ so the proposed answer  of $20160$ is absurdly large.